# Can an entry in an ArrayProxy be bound to a property on some other object?

Tags: ember.js

I created an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ULwW/).  I'll also drop the code here:

Javascript:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

TypeA = Ember.Object.extend({
  propertyA: ""
});

TypeB = Ember.Object.extend({
  propertyB: ""
});

App.someController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: []
});

var aa = TypeA.create({propertyA: "aa"});
var ab = TypeA.create({propertyA: "ab"});
var ba = TypeB.create({propertyB: "ba"});
var bb = TypeB.create({propertyB: "bb"});

// I'm probably just copying the string here so sort of realizing
// that the binding "breaks", however I don't get how to maintain the "bond".
App.someController.pushObject(aa.get("propertyA"));
App.someController.pushObject(ab.get("propertyA"));
App.someController.pushObject(ba.get("propertyB"));
App.someController.pushObject(bb.get("propertyB"));

// I'd like this to update the value "aa" in the list
aa.set('propertyA', "AA");
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#collection contentBinding="App.someController" tagName="ul"}}
    {{content}}
  {{/collection}}
</script>
```

So the source of the entries in `someController` can be various different objects, but the bond between the property of the object and the entry in someController should be preserved.  Any easy way to do this?  I thought of wrapping the values in `someController` in some object or view but I can't find how to create a binding to a non "global" object (all the bindings I saw seemed to use a full "global" path, eg `"App.someObject.property"`)

Any ideas much appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured it out with help from Veebs post.  I wound up wrapping the strings (originating from the property) in an object of the form:

```
Ember.Object.create({
    obj: obj,
    out: function() { 
        return this.get('obj').get(property); 
    }.property('obj.' + property)
});
```

Evidently, when a property of an object changes, the object is (somehow) marked changed with it, so by saying that `out` depends on `obj` it picks up changes in obj.property.

So here is the original code with the changes:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

TypeA = Ember.Object.extend({
    propertyA: "",
    propertyC: ""
});

TypeB = Ember.Object.extend({
    propertyB: "",
});

App.someController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: []
});

var a = TypeA.create({propertyA: "aa", propertyC: "ac"});
var b = TypeA.create({propertyB: "bb"});

function createWrapper(obj, property) {
    return Ember.Object.create({
        obj: obj,
        out: function() { 
            return this.get('obj').get(property); 
        }.property('obj.' + property)
    });
}

App.someController.pushObject(createWrapper(a, "propertyA"));
App.someController.pushObject(createWrapper(a, "propertyC"));
App.someController.pushObject(createWrapper(b, "propertyB"));

setTimeout(function() {
    a.set('propertyA', "AA");
    a.set('propertyC', "AC");
    b.set('propertyB', "BB");
    a.set('propertyA', "AA2"); 
},2000);
```

...and the (slightly changed) template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#collection contentBinding="App.someController" tagName="ul"}}
        {{content.out}}
    {{/collection}}
</script>
```

(also available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZpZSC/))

Thanks for the help!

Edit: Second thought, this didn't work, at least not when the update happens after some time.  Goddamn it.
Edit: Updated to fixed version, yay.

Comment: Better yet another version: [http://jsfiddle.net/r6f3P/](http://jsfiddle.net/r6f3P/).

Comment: And it didn't work in the end, if you do the changes after some time they don't update, #$%.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are after: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qfxrr/).

I think you need to push the objects into the array rather than the property.

```
App.someController.pushObject(aa);
App.someController.pushObject(ab);
App.someController.pushObject(ba);
App.someController.pushObject(bb);
```

Then, in your template, reference the required property.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#collection contentBinding="App.someController" tagName="ul"}}
        {{content.propertyA}}
        {{content.propertyB}}
    {{/collection}}
</script>
```

By pushing `aa.get("propertyA")` into your array, you are just pushing a simple string and the relationship between the object and the array is broken.

I would recommend creating a computed property that will figure out if `propertyA` or `propertyB` needs to be returned for any one object.  Then, you can use the computed property in your collection.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#collection contentBinding="App.someController" tagName="ul"}}
        {{content.newComputedProperty}}
    {{/collection}}
</script>
```

Comment: This got me going a bit, but I needed more flexibility then the computed property in case two different properties on the same object would need to be added to the array.  A bit strange case maybe..

Sorry I can't give you an up-vote, I don't have good enough reputation yet. :/